# Need to copy date from one column into another column for a range of rows between two different colored rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am admittedly a VBA noob who needs some major help trying to figure out the following.

So in my data set I have rows with green backgrounds and rows with red backgrounds.

I need to take the date and time from column S in the row with the green background, and copy it into column D for each row between the green row and the red row, inclusive of the colored rows.

I then need to take the date and time from column s in the row with the red background, and copy that into column E for each row in the same range, again inclusive of the colored rows.

This needs to be done multiple times per sets of data with a variable number of rows between the green row and the red row each time.

I am thinking that it makes sense to use the R1C1 cell addressing instead of the A1. What I am specifically lost with is first of all, how to detect the background color of each cell, and secondly, how to count the number of rows between the green and the red cells, and thirdly how I go about reading from row to row. Am I simply treating it like an array of known size?

I am new to VBA with Excel and am admittedly struggling with quite a bit here. I am looking through various books, tutorials, etc, but I could REALLY use some help!!

Comment: If you're struggling then you've written something. [Edit] your question to include what you've written.

Comment: Can you at least add an image of how your data looks like and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little unclear. For detecting background color, you could use `.Interior.ColorIndex`, for counting rows and getting reading from row to row you need to use loop formulas.

This simple sub check if background color of cell A is green and if so, copy value from cell in column B to cell in column C.

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 7
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```